# Prefix Folder structure for Zend

Tags: zend-framework, prefix, special-folders

If i have a url such as this `http://example.com/controller/action` every thing works find. as expected. However i need to deploy this and in deployment things change a bit to `htttp://deploy.com/stuff/pile/controller/action` is there any way i can control this in zend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this route to your Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoute() {
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute(
        'prefix_route',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('stuff/pile/:controller/:action',
            array('controller' => $front->getRequest()->getControllerName(),
                  'action' => $front->getRequest()->getActionName())));
    );
}
```